# Specific behaviour of the first li element in ul and div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have following problem:
in a **div** there are for example three **ul** elements. Each of those **ul** elements contains one or more **li** elements.
What I want, is to add a specific attribute to the very first **li** which is in the first **ul**, but the way other **li** won't have the same behaviour.

```
<div class="class1">
    <ul>
      <li>          
        <div class="type">
            some text
        </div>
        <p>some more text</p>       
      </li> 
      <li>          
        <div class="type">
            text2
        </div>
            <p>more text 2</p>          
      </li> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>   
        <div class="type">
            some new text
        </div>
        <p>more some new text</p>       
       </li>    
       <li>         
        <div class="type">
            text 3
        </div>
            <p>more text 3</p>      
       </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks following:

```
.class1 ul:first-child li {
    border-top: #000000 1px solid;
}
```

But this doesn't work the way I wish and since I'm pretty new to CSS, I have no idea what can I do without using JS. 
Does anyone have any advice for me please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the first `li` as well with `:first-child`:

```
.class1 ul:first-child li:first-child
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x20htue7/)

Comment: oh so simple :) Thank you very much Jacob, you just saved me hours of work :)

Comment: @middleendian no problem :) remember to select this answer as accepted if it fixed your problem